# Firebase CDN unreachable from some networks

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using firebaseui in a web app and I get this error in the console logs:

> Loading failed for the  with source “https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/3.5.2/firebaseui.js”.

The auth UI itself, as expected, doesn't load. The domain cdn.firebase.com resolves to:

> Name: f6.shared.global.fastly.net
>
> Address: 151.101.154.202

It resolves to a different IP address from hosts from which the auth UI loads. Is there anything I could do to ensure that the firebase auth UI loads reliably regardless of where the host is located?

Thanks,
Abhishek

Comment: It looks like that release might not have propagated to one of the edge caches. Can you [file a bug report](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/), so the team can follow up and ensure all caches are up to date?

Comment: I did, the person who picked it up said that since at their location they're unable to reproduce this, they will not diagnose it further.

Comment: Hmmm.... can you give me the case number, so I can have a look?

Comment: Sure, the case number is 00016476. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase UI Web library is hosted on both the cdn.firebase.com and gstatic.com CDNs.

Try using this instead:

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.5.2/firebase-ui-auth.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/ui/3.5.2/firebase-ui-auth.css" />
```

Comment: The resource is available through gstatic.com on the network in question. Thanks.